# $A,B \in M(n,\mathbb C)$ with $AB=BA$ , then does there exist $P \in M(n,\mathbb C)$ and $f(X) , g(X) \in \mathbb C[X]$ such that $A=f(P), B=g(P)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $A,B \in M(n,\mathbb C)$ ; if $\exists P \in M(n, \mathbb C)$ and $f(X) , g(X) \in \mathbb C[X]$ such that $A=f(P) , B=g(P)$ then $AB=BA$ . Now suppose $AB=BA$ ; then does there exist $P \in M(n,\mathbb C)$ and $f(X) , g(X) \in \mathbb C[X]$ such that $A=f(P)$ and $ B=g(P)$ ? If this is not true in general , then what if we assume that both $A,B$ are diagonalizable ? Is it true then ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the original...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, this is true in the case that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable: if $A$ and $B$ are diagonlizable and commute, then they are simultaneously diagonalizable.  Suppose then, without loss of generality, that $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.  We have
$$
A = \pmatrix{a_1\\&\ddots\\&&a_n} \quad B = \pmatrix{b_1\\&\ddots\\&&b_n}
$$
If we take
$$
P = \pmatrix{1 \\ & \ddots \\ & &n}
$$
Then it suffices to find interpolating polynomials $f,g$ such that $f(j) = a_j$ and $g(j) = b_j$ for $j = 1,\dots,n$.

---

I don't think this is true in general.  I believe the following is a counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0\\&&1\\&&&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&0&1\\&&&0}
$$